# passing const as this argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, constants

I have the following:
first a string that is *not* a constant

```
std::string anId;
```

an object that *is* a constant

```
const Object * object;
```

This object has a method like

```
 const std::shared_ptr<RawData> GetRawData(const std::string &);
```

and there is a function like this

```
getData(const std::shared_ptr<RawData> raw_ptr);
```

So, when I do this:

```
getData(object->GetRawData(anId));
```

I get the error

```
error: passing ‘const Object ’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         int stat = getData(object->GetRawData(anId));
```

Except the first string, I don't see how I am not passing constants...
I wonder where is the error coming from

Comment: you are not only passing the string. The object itself is also an implicit parameter to the method

Comment: @idclev463035818 so which non-constant I am passing to a constant argument? I don't see it

Comment: `object` is `const` while `GetRawData` can only be called on a non-constant object. Its explained in the duplicate (see link at the top)

Comment: methods should be `const` be default unless they need to modify the object

Comment: Other than making the method `const` is there any other way to correct it. The file with `GetRawData` is used in a lot of other parts of the code (it is huge) and I prefer not to break other people's modules...

Comment: you will not break code (unless someone is doing weird stuff). You will actually make other code better by doing that change. A `const` method can be called on a `const` object *and* on a non-const object. The other way around is more likely to cause problems.